# Importing GPX files into ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop Basic?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, gpx

I want to import GPX files into ArcMap. There is a good answer
[Adding GPX files into Arcmap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16402/what-is-the-simplest-method-to-add-gpx-files-into-arcmap) for version 10.1 using the GPX to Features tool but that is not available in 10.3. I think it has been superceded by Smart Mapping in 10.3, which is not in ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop, Basic.

Currently I am using QGIS and the GPS plug-in
http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/plugins_gps.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool [GPX To Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/gpx-to-features.htm) in which you can import or convert the point information inside a GPX file into point features. It is available in ArcGIS 10.3 basic license as well. You can access the tool from `ArcToolbox -> Conversion Tools -> From GPS`